# Read configuration values from js file AngularJS 1.5.X

Tags: angularjs

I want read the config values for based on env, here the constraint I have to read the values from config.js file and entries in the file like below :

```
config.js:

baseUrl='/home',
abcUrl='/abc'
```

now I need to get the baseUrl and abcUrl into one of my service, I tried the below approach:

service.js

```
factory.getdetails = function(){
                var mainInfo = $http.get('./config.js').success(function(response) {
                    console.log(response.baseUrl);
                    });
            }
```

when I am trying to response.baseUrl and I'm getting "undefined", I would like to get '/home' any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Your file should be a valid JSON file (not JavaScript source file), containing a JSON object with your 2 properties, you should use `then()` rather than `success()`, and `response.data.baseUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

Use .then instead of .success also access the data property of the response

```
factory.getdetails = function(){
   $http.get('./config.json').then(function(response) {
          console.log(response.data.baseUrl);
   });
}
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/B85LOoNPKfPiZatprlWd?p=info)**

Comment: I'm still getting "undefined"  when I have response.data.baseUrl

Comment: check the attached demo

Comment: $scope.gridOptions1 = response.data, If I use I am getting baseUrl='/home',
abcUrl='/abc' as out put, but if you try response.data.baseUrl you will get "undefined"

Comment: @Kumar read my comment, under your question. Don't load a JavaScript source file. Load data, as JSON.

Comment: @JBNizet, Agreed with you. but unfortunately my requirement is to use .js file instead of JSON :(

Comment: @Kumar definitely you need JSON , https://plnkr.co/edit/B85LOoNPKfPiZatprlWd?p=preview

Comment: This requirement makes no sense. Or the js file should be part of your application source code, and you shouldn't load it using an ajax request. If you add a script in your HTML, before the one for your app, which loads this file, then these two global variables are accessible from anywhere in the code.

Comment: If we make it as a global variable, I think there is a chance to change the url (It is  easy to hacking) correct me If I am wrong

Comment: what do you mean by global variable here??

Comment: If we add that config.js file directly in index.html and try to access the the values , then those variable become global

Answer (score 0):

If this is just the configuration that you want to save it would be appropriate to create a json file and have these configuration.
Then you can use

```js
$http.get('fileurl').then(
function(response) {
   console.log(response.data);
}, function() {
console.log('error fetching the configuration');
});
```